# How to integrate Stripe Connect with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

So im at the part where you sign in your Stripe account and it redirects you to my website once done.

I dont know what to do next and the documentation is difficult to comprehend because i dont have any expierence in node.js

I just need some guidance in what to do.

Comment: The next part is to use the `authorization_code`: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth#token-request

Answer (score 2):

> 1. After Clicking on 'Authorize' button, at your redirected URI it will give you Authorization code.
> 2. After getting Authorization code you should make post request to get details of connected user account.

It will give you `json` like this

```
{
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "stripe_publishable_key": PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
   "scope": "read_write",
   "livemode": false,
   "stripe_user_id": USER_ID,
   "refresh_token": REFRESH_TOKEN,
   "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN
}
```

> 3. Now by using USER_ID and ACCESS_TOKEN and REFRESH_TOKEN, you can make charges on connected user account.

Answer (score 0):

1 Use https://github.com/gtramontina/stripe-angular on Client

2.Use https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node on server